# CommandError: No fixture named 'myapp' found

Tags: django

I created a json file 
myapp/fixtures/initial_data.json , which has the data to be loaded.

But when I run

```
python manage.py loaddata myapp
```

Getting below error

**CommandError: No fixture named 'myapp' found.**

What could be  reason for the error?

Answer (score 10):

```
python manage.py loaddata myapp/fixtures/initial_data.json
```

you need to pass the file name with full path

Answer (score 3):

`python manage.py loaddata` should be followed by fixture name, not app name.

So instead of typing:

`python manage.py loaddata myapp`

you should type

`python manage.py loaddata initial_data`

or

`python manage.py loaddata initial_data.json`

(Of course full path is fine too if you don't mind the long string.)

For more information, please check the [official document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#loaddata).

Answer (score 1):

You can try `python manage.py loaddata */fixtures/*.json` this will load all your fixtures from all applications. (if there are any).

Comment: you don't need the forward slash though, it should be python manage.py loaddata *fixtures/*.json

Answer (score 1):

You should write the Full Path Of the code
Like `python manage.py loaddata my_app/data/__init.json`
Its Should will be work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running the command from the right directory. For me, simply moving to the right directory fixed this issue.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try `python manage.py loaddata 'myapp'` instead of `python manage.py loaddata myapp`. It should work. Make sure you are in the right directory (a.k.a. the directory where manage.py is).

Answer (score 0):

Experienced this error and tried the solutions mentioned above but it didn't work. What had happened was that I was on the wrong branch. You can check to ensure that you're doing the `python manage.py loaddata --myapp file.json` on the correct branch that has the file.

Answer (score 0):

Need to check your directory now.
If your directory are located at apps like this `C:\Users\XXX\myapp>` then
`python manage.py loaddata fixtures/initial_data.json`

**NOTE** :
If you have done any changes in the `myapp` you have to do `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` first before you loaddata.

Answer (score -1):

None of these solutions worked. I needed to add ".json" to the end of the file name. Then `python manage.py loaddata my_data.json` worked.